# Allocate observations in groups

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, allocation

I was wondering how I can allocate my dataset the best.
I have a dataset with 3 clusters. Based on posterior probabilities I want allocate the respondents to groups.
For example, respondent 1 has: 0.10 chance for cluster 1, 0.30 chance for cluster 2 and 0.60 chance for cluster 3. How do I allocate respondent 1 to cluster 3 then?
Below is a small df:

```
dput(head(new1)[,c(1:3)])
structure(list(comp.1 = c(0.06, 0.03, 0, 0.03, 0, 0), comp.2 = c(0.61, 
0.42, 0.07, 0.41, 0.31, 0.41), comp.3 = c(0.33, 0.56, 0.93, 0.56, 
0.69, 0.59)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6"))
```

In the end I want to end up with comp1, comp2, and comp3, all of them filled with the posterior probabilities which belong to each group.

Hope you can help me out!

EDIT:

```
comp1 <- subset(new, new$comp.1 >= 0.6)
comp2 <- subset(new, new$comp.2 >= 0.6)
comp3 <- subset(new, new$comp.3 >= 0.6)
```

Above is what I did, but my teacher told me that I should allocate respondents to a component based on the highest chance, instead of a certain value, what I did above (0.6).

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean or how you want your result to be (please show expected output), but I think you are looking for `max.col(df)`

Comment: I've made it more clear in the question @Sotos